# 'Uncaught Error: type arguments should not be null: T' when updating pubspec in angular dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm tring to update my libs, i got to start, but i'm getting this error and now I have no idea where or how to fix.

https://pastebin.com/cTGmBjKY

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.0.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  ng_bootstrap: ^1.1.1
  angular: ^5.3.0
  angular_components: ^0.13.0+1
  angular_forms: ^2.1.1
  angular_router: ^2.0.0-alpha+21
  rxdart: ^0.20.0
  firebase: ^5.0.3
  googleapis: ^0.52.0
  googleapis_auth: ^0.2.5+2
  service_worker: ^0.2.3
  sass: ^1.5.0
  markdown: ^2.0.2
  intl: ^0.15.8

dev_dependencies:
  sass_builder: ^2.0.0
  angular_test: ^2.2.0
  build_runner: ^1.2.3
  build_test: ^0.10.3
  build_web_compilers: ^2.1.0
  test: ^1.0.0
```

webdev-2.0.7

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`build_web_compilers` 2.x and Dart SDK 2.3 are broken around JS interop. The next SDK release should fix it - in the mean time you'll want to downgrade back to `build_web_compilers` `^1.0.0`